# Graph drawing library for Flash

Tags: apache-flex, flash, graph, data-visualization, gnuplot

I have a bunch of numeric stats data gathered over time.

I need to show it as a line graph to user in a HTML page. I want to render graph on client. It would be perfect if graph would be interactive (allowing user to scale, scroll, toggle graph lines visibility etc.).

Is there any decent free graph drawing library for Flash / Flex (or, perhaps, JavaScript with Canvas)?

I'd prefer something gnuplot-like, but will deal with anything that is sane enough.

**Update:** Something *besides* [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two (free) libraries come to mind:

- [Dojo Chart](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/06/a-beginners-guide-to-dojo-charting-part-1-of-2/) (Javascript + Canvas)
- [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/) (Flash)

Answer (score 1):

There is [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org) for Actionscript 3. Flex Professional has a charting library as well (But is not free).